# Rollback AppCenter Update

Tags: display, release-juno

I just installed a new update from AppCenter in elementary OS 5.0.  It was one package.  According to my `apt` history log, it was switchboard-plug-power.  This update has made my laptop unusable on a dock.  Plugging the laptop into the dock will cause no monitor to work, not even the laptop monitor and I have to force shutdown.

How can I revert from 2.3.5, the updated version, to 2.3.4, the previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based on this answer from Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get), there is a command line option to install the previous version of a package, but it doesn't look like Elementary's repositories still have it available:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall switchboard-plug-power=2.3.4+r609~ubuntu5.0.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.3.4+r609~ubuntu5.0.1' for 'switchboard-plug-power' was not found
```

So, Elementary doesn't seem to keep old versions (at all) in their repository manifest. However, I was [was able to find them available for direct download on Elementary's server](http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/s/switchboard-plug-power/). So for example if you had an AMD64 system, you would download that .deb file and install it manually.

After downloading the file, use `dpkg` to manually install the older version. For example, if I did that with my Intel 64-bit computer, I'd do:

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/s/switchboard-plug-power/switchboard-plug-power_2.3.4+r609~ubuntu5.0.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i switchboard-plug-power_2.3.4+r609~ubuntu5.0.1_amd64.deb
```

It would then proceed to downgrade the package:

```
dpkg: warning: downgrading switchboard-plug-power from 2.3.5+r634~ubuntu5.0.1 to 2.3.4+r609~ubuntu5.0.1
(Reading database ... 306254 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack switchboard-plug-power_2.3.4+r609~ubuntu5.0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking switchboard-plug-power (2.3.4+r609~ubuntu5.0.1) over (2.3.5+r634~ubuntu5.0.1) ...
Setting up switchboard-plug-power (2.3.4+r609~ubuntu5.0.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1) ...
```

If you want to prevent future automatic upgrades, you can run `apt-mark hold switchboard-plug-power`.